# Laravel show array in console from table even with null values

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, controller, console

[image: 1]

This is my table: `hms_bbr_category_2`. It's just a test table, ignore the gibberish.

I need to get a `console.log` working so that just in case values there will be any null data when I add new rows

Here is my Laravel controller: (my model is `HmsBbrCategory` and connects to the table)

```
public function fetchcategory() {
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::all();
    return response()->json([
        'all_categories'->$all_categories,
    ]);
}
```

**Ajax**

```
function fetchcategory() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response){
            console.log(response.all_categories);
        }
    });
}
```

My console is giving out this error when I try to show the table:

[image: 2]

> message: "Trying to get property (list of the table arrays) of non-object"

Does the error show because some of my columns have null? what can I do to output the data even with the null values?

Comment: I think you have syntax error. Use ```=>``` instead of ```->``` in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error while returning response  `'all_categories'->$all_categories,`

```
public function fetchcategory(){
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::all();
    return response()->json([
        'all_categories'=>$all_categories,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error while returning your `JSON` response in your `fetchcategory()` method:

In place of this line of code:

```
return response()->json([
    'all_categories'->$all_categories,
]);
```

Use this line of code:

```
return Response::json(array('all_categories' => $all_categories));
```